# Detect if PowerShell is running as administrator

Tags: powershell

How can I tell in my scripts if PowerShell is running with administrator privileges?

I need to know because I'm trying to run a program that requires the ability to open protected ports.

Comment: You mat consider to elevate permissions as described in [Gaining administrator privileges in PowerShell](http://serverfault.com/a/12306) answer

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
[bool](([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).groups -match "S-1-5-32-544")
```

Breaking apart what this does:

- `[bool]` - Cast the end result to a `bool`.
- `[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()` - Retrieves the `WindowsIdentity` for the currently running user.
- `(...).groups` - Access the `groups` property of the identity to find out what user groups the identity is a member of.
- `-match "S-1-5-32-544"` checks to see if `groups` contains the [Well Known SID](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/81d92bba-d22b-4a8c-908a-554ab29148ab?redirectedfrom=MSDN) of the Administrators group, the identity will only contain it if "run as administrator" was used.

Comment: Instead of just posting a line of code, can you please explain what it does? This helps future visitors in understanding and adapting it, if necessary.

Comment: BOOO. Give this man more upvotes

Comment: I prefer the answer by @Bill_Stewart below since it is free of magic strings.

Comment: Instead of using `-match` and typecasting: `[Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Groups -contains 'S-1-5-32-544'`

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley Nice one! Definitely an improvement over all those other multi-line solutions!

Comment: How to use this solution if its for a different process? Like notepad or mspaint

Answer (score 111):

```
([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] `
  [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent() `
).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)
```

This retrieves the current Windows identity and returns `$true` if the current identity has the Administrator role (i.e., is running elevated).

Comment: While the accepted answer is correct, this answer is much more clear, especially to someone who may read your script six months from now.

Answer (score 64):

In Powershell 4.0 you can use [requires](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_requires) at the top of your script:

```
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator
```

Outputs:

> The script 'MyScript.ps1' cannot be run because it contains a "#requires"       statement for
> running as Administrator. The current Windows PowerShell session is not running as Administrator. Start Windows
> PowerShell by  using the Run as Administrator option, and then try running the script again.

Comment: what if you want a function that exits if not ran by admin?

Comment: @KolobCanyon - There's no such thing as running _only_ a PowerShell function elevated; the entire PowerShell process is either elevated or not.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart yes, but you can `return` if the user is not admin :)

Comment: @KolobCanyon - you can only elevate the PowerShell _process_; you cannot elevate a single _function_. That's why the `#Requires -RunAsAdministrator` is useful: It prevents the _entire script_ from running if you're not elevated.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Yeah, I'll have to use that at some point.

Comment: The requires link isn't working for me.  Perhaps [about_Requires](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_requires) is the new URL?

Answer (score 0):

Your code :

---

```
invoke-command -computername cavl-ghwwsc3 -command { ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] 
  [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)}
```

---

is working fine but how to launch it remotely in current user session (not in powershell elevate admin rights because it return my admin isadmin value to remote computer, not current log user if this user isadmin.